# JAAS equivalent for .NET

Tags: .net, security, equivalent

Is there a JAAS equivalent for .NET? We have several Java EE product with JAAS. It works quite good. We have written several own modules. In addition to the Java EE products, we also want to develop another .NET/REST/JSON/Dojotoolkit produkt. Is there something similar to JAAS for .NET? I would like to be able to do the following:

1. Transparent handling of security for HTTP/REST sessions. I would like to require a role based on the URL.
2. Access to the roles and user info in the .NET business layer.
3. Possibility to use standard modules for AD/LDAP and user/password in DB.
4. Possibility to write own login modules.
5. No need to manually handle the HTTP session or user objects.

Comment: Good time to learn [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @I4V. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx) looks like it solves at least 3 and 4.

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82tywhc6(v=vs.80).aspx) - it explains how you can convert the JAAS configuration to .NET via a tool that built in.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelPerrenoud. The link was a very good starting point for direct me from familiar JEE concepts to .NET counterparts

Comment: @j.hedin, I'm glad I could be of some assistance!